# SwiftUI prevent animation when updating State

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view, that displays an image and when I scroll, this image changes in opacity, scale and offset.

```
Image(...)
  .resizable()
  .opacity(artworkOpacity)
  .scaleEffect(artworkScale)
  .offset(artworkOffset)
```

This is defined in `struct MyView: View { ... }`.
At the app level I set

```
MyView()
 .animation(.default)
 .transition(someTransition)
```

This works well, except for when updating those 3 state variables (opacity, scale and offset), those are animated too!
Adding `.animation(nil)` at the end fixes that, however the transition breaks, the image is the only view that is not transitioning properly.

How can I make the animation only happen during a transition and not while updating state?

I tried with various combinations of enabling and disabling the animation in that view as well as with `withAnimation(nil) { // update State }`

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, so is the image supposed to animate scale, opacity and offset while scrolling, but not animate during some other state change?

Comment: Are you looking `.animation(_:value:)`, where an animation only occurs when a certain value changes? That would stop an animation happening when some other unrelated `@State` variable changes.

Comment: @SuperTully yes, so let's suppose I have an animation of the entire full screen view to the left and to the right, depending on which button is pressed. So the entire view is replaced in an animation. But once I am on one of those views, the UI should no longer be animated. I tried with that, but I have no idea when the transition happens

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand.  If you want it to animate only during the transition, have you tried a ternary operator? Like so: `.animation(willTransition ? .default : nil)` This should theoretically work; to set the animation to nothing anyway, but in practice I've found that setting it to nil may not always work, which could be a bug.  Also, you'd have to setup a willTransition Bool variable too, but that shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

There is `.animation(..., value: ...)`, where animation is only added to the view, if the value (which is an equatable), has changed. So the entire view is not affected by the animation, unless the state that defines the current view changes and transition begins.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without the full code, but you can add Animation directly to the Transition instead of the whole object.

```
.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).animation(.easeInOut))
```

Comment: That doesn't animate the views as I want it to, but good to know! At least it just quickly replaces views, while if I set .`animation(.default).transition(...)` it works as expected (like a navigation transition).